# C++ Operator Problem

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I don't know if this question is already answered on stackoverflow. But I simply can not find the right keyword to search for.

I inserted some stripped down version of my code below.

So basically what I'm trying to do in my main(), is to subtract 122 from t2. I suppose my compiler converts the integer to a Timestamp object automatically and then subtracts it as showed in 'Timestamp.cpp'.

But when it arrives at t4 it doesn't convert it and give me the following error:

> no match for 'operator-' in '722 - t1'

I'm 100% sure that it is possible. But how?

Maybe I'm totally wrong about converting... So please do hesitate to correct me, I'm trying to learn something.

**STRIPPED DOWN CODE:**

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "Timestamp.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Timestamp t3(t2 - 122);
    cout << "T3 = " << t3 << endl;
    Timestamp t4(722 - t1);
    cout << "T4 = " << t4 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Timestamp.h

```cpp
#ifndef TIJDSDUUR_H
#define TIJDSDUUR_H

using namespace std;

class Timestamp {
    public:
        Timestamp(int);
        Timestamp operator- (const Timestamp &t);
    private:
        int hour;
        int min;
};
```

Timestamp.cpp

```cpp
Timestamp::Timestamp(int m) : hour(0), min(m) {

}

Timestamp Timestamp::operator- (const Timestamp &t) {
    Timestamp temp;

    temp.hour = hour;
    temp.min = min;

    temp.hour -= t.hour;
    temp.min -= t.min;

    while(temp.min < 0.00) {
        temp.hour--;
        temp.min += 60;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Contrary to what the other answers propose, you do not need to provide an specialized `operator-` that takes an `int` and a `Timestamp`, rather you can (and probably should) make `operator-` a non-member function:

```
Timestamp operator-( Timestamp lhs, Timestamp const & rhs ); // Returns a timestamp?? really??
```

That way the compiler is free to apply conversions to both the left hand side and the right hand side operands, and use the implicit conversion from `int` to `Timestamp`.

You can read a short description on design and implementation of operator overloads [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/operator-overloading.html), or you can search in the [C++-faq] tag in SO for "operator overload".

Comment: Why not make `lhs` also const?

Comment: +1, though I also don't see the reason for non-symmetry in the types of parameters. Also, it might be worth noting that you can define a non-member function inside the class, if you mark it as `friend`.

Comment: @Nawaz because the canonical implementation will be `lhs -= rhs; return lhs;`

Comment: @Nawaz: The common idiom would be to implement that operator in terms of `operator-=` as: `Timestamp operator-( Timestamp lhs, Timestamp const & rhs ) { return lhs -= rhs; }` The first argument is *copied* and modified internally. This can be slightly better performing than taking the two arguments by constant reference in the case where the first argument is an rvalue expression. In particular in this example, because the first argument is the result of a conversion from `int` and *is* an rvalue, and taking it by value avoids having to construct a different `Timestamp` internally.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Totally agree. +1.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the following non-member function:

```
Timestamp operator-(int left, const Timestamp &right)
{
    //define
}
```

By the way, make the member `operator-()` const  function as:

```
Timestamp operator-(const Timestamp &t) const;
                                       //^^^^^ this makes the function const
```

If you make this const, only the `right-left` would work, because `right` is const object, and so only const member  function can be invoked on it.

---

I noticed that you've a constructor that takes `int` as parameter. This constructor can behave like implicit conversion function from `int` to `TimeStamp` which means, you don't need to define two `operator-()` functions (one as member function which you already have defined, and other as non-member function as I suggested above). Instead, you can define only one *friend* function of this type:

```
Timestamp operator-(const Timestamp &left, const Timestamp &right)
{
  //define
}
```

You've to make `friend` of the class, as it needs to access the `private` members of the class. However, @David provided a better solution. But I'm keeping this solution only for academic purpose.

Comment: You do not *need* to provide it, there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `Timestamp`, so the best suggestion would be to make `operator-` a free function altogether and you can provide a single implementation that can be used for `1 - ts` and `ts - 1`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Ohh.. I didn't notice the constructor that implicitly convert `int` to `TimeStamp`.

Comment: That operator implementation is just wrong. In normal algebras, X - Y != Y - X (where X != Y). It's doubtful rthe OP is doing any exotic algebra...

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson: God. What happened to my logic. I just thought I I could implement it that way. It would have worked if it was `+` instead of `-`. Thanks for pointing out incorrect logic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see:

First, your constructor is taking a parameter of type int.  Your operator is returning type TimeStamp, which you're then passing to the constructor.  You haven't specified a conversion from TimeStamp to int, so this won't work!

Second, your operator is taking a parameter of type timestamp, but you appear to subtracting an int from it when you're actually using it.  It has no idea what an int is though, because you didn't tell it!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Timestamp::operator-(int)` allows you to subtract an integer from a Timestamp object. It does not allow you to subtract Timestamps from integers.

You need to add operator- as a free function

```
Timestamp operator-(int, const Timestamp&);
```

This needs to be a friend of Timestamp as it needs to access the private members.